# Edit when an onChanged event is called in LiveData

Tags: java, android, equals, android-livedata

I have created a simple app that writes to log when an onChanged event is called. Currently the onChanged is called everytime i increment MyInteger via setValue. I would like to amend so onChanged is only called for specific events E.g. only call onChanged when MyInteger > 3. I have tried to override the equals method in MyInteger but it didn't work. How can i achieve this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MainActivityViewModel mMainActivityViewModel;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        MyInteger myInteger = new MyInteger(0);

        mMainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
        mMainActivityViewModel.getLiveData2().observe(this, new Observer<MyInteger>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(MyInteger myInteger) {
                Log.d("onChanged:", String.valueOf(myInteger.integer));
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myInteger.incrementByOne();
                mMainActivityViewModel.getLiveData2().setValue(myInteger);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public MutableLiveData<MyInteger> myIntegerMutableLiveData;

    public MainActivityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MyInteger> getLiveData2() {

        if (myIntegerMutableLiveData == null) {
            myIntegerMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
        return myIntegerMutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyInteger {

 MyInteger object.
    public int integer;

    public MyInteger(Integer integer) {
        this.integer = integer;
    }

    public void incrementByOne() {
        integer++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyInteger myInteger = (MyInteger) o;
        return myInteger.integer > 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(integer);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't this just a simple if statement ? i'm confused..

Comment: i would like the  onChanged to implicitly handle the event. I believe there is a way to do this with method distinctUntilChanged in Transformations class.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you just do

```
if(myInteger > 3){
    mMainActivityViewModel.getLiveData2().setValue(myInteger);
}
```

overriding the equals isnt going to do anything, when you set the value with `setValue` in your LiveData thats when onChanged gets called. If anything you need to extend the LiveData class

Comment: not sure if this would work, OP's code is quite confusing but i think it would have to be `if(myInteger.integer >3)` because myInteger is an object/class

Comment: possibly but still the same idea

Comment: is there no way to do this with the built in LiveData functionality? see section 7 in https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1#5e38

Comment: @mairs8 LiveData is just a Pub/Sub, what you linked is using the `Room` SQLight library which is query based results of a database

Comment: Also `Flowable` is RxJava